# Function to write all even numbers from form

Tags: javascript, forms, function, loops

I have html form of 16 fields. User enters number in each field
 and function have to sort only even numbers and show them.

> // JS function for even numbers and printing out in paragraph //

```
function evenNumbers() {
  var numbers = document.getElementsByClassName("formInput");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i <= numbers.length - 1; i++) {
    if (numbers[i].value % 2 == 0) {
      document.getElementById("even").innerHTML = "Even numbers are: " + numbers[i].value;
      else {
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
```

After I fill in form, I do get text and value, but only last one.

Question: How can I get function to write me all even numbers in one
line?

> Example: 2,4,6,8 etc...

What must I type in or change this function. Thank you all in advance

Comment: First your else is inside `if` which is wrong. Second, you are using `=`. This will replace value of `innerHTML`. Use `+= ` to append

Comment: by default numbers in a form will be a string not a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your `else` is inside of `if` statement, which is wrong. Check that there is no need to add a `continue;` in your `for` loop as you are doing only one action.

Also check that all numbers that come from the form inputs are strings, than you have to get numbers with [Unary plus (+) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) `var num = +numbers[i].value;`

Finally, i have created an array `evenNumbers` to collect all even numbers and based on that you can show up you message with a ternary operator
- As the numbers are in an array, you can join them with [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) `evenNumbers.join(', ')`

Code:

```js
function evenNumbers() {
  var numbers = document.getElementsByClassName('formInput'),
      evenNumbers = [];

  for (var i = 0, l = numbers.length - 1; i <= l; i++) {
    var num = +numbers[i].value;
    (num && num % 2 === 0) && evenNumbers.push(num);
  }

  document.getElementById('even').innerHTML = (evenNumbers.length) 
    ? 'Even numbers are: ' + evenNumbers.join(', ') 
    : 'There are no even numbers.';
}
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" class="formInput">
  <input type="text" class="formInput">
  <input type="text" class="formInput">
  <input type="text" class="formInput">
  <input type="text" class="formInput">
  <input type="text" class="formInput">
  <input type="button" value="Show Even Numbers" onclick="evenNumbers()"/>
</form>

<hr>
<p>Result: <span id="even"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good idea to mix calculation with DOM changes, you might need `evenNumbers` for different use-cases as well:

```
function evenNumbers(numbers) {
  var i;
  var result = [];
  for (i = 0; i <= numbers.length - 1; i++) {
    if (numbers[i].value % 2 == 0) {
      result.push(numbers[i].value);
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Use it like this:

```
  document.getElementById("even").innerHTML = "Even numbers are: " + evenNumbers(document.getElementsByClassName("formInput")).join(",");
```

Notice that this is a general approach where you can pass the numbers and thus you will be able to reuse your `function` elsewhere as well.

Comment: In your code `numbers[i].value` it is an string and also check that the `else` is inside the `if` statement

Comment: @YosvelQuintero, thank you for the constructive criticism. I have removed the else, as it was unnecessary (came from the op's question I did not pay enough attention). numbers[i].value is a string indeed, but that is not a problem, as it will work well with the % operator.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function evenNumbers() {
  var numbers = document.getElementsByClassName("formInput");
  var i;
  
  for (i = 0; i <= numbers.length - 1; i++) 
  {
    if (numbers[i].value % 2 == 0) 
    {
         document.getElementById("even").innerHTML += ", " + numbers[i].value;
    }
  }
  
  document.getElementById("even").innerHTML = "Even numbers : " + document.getElementById("even").innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<input class="formInput" type="text">
<input class="formInput" type="text">
<input class="formInput" type="text">
<input class="formInput" type="text">
<input class="formInput" type="text">
<input class="formInput" type="text">
<input class="formInput" type="text">

<div id="even"></div>

<button onclick="evenNumbers()">Find even</button>
```

When you write

```
document.getElementById("even").innerHTML = "Even numbers are: " + numbers[i].value;
```

It does write all values but the value gets replaced when it finds the next even number. You are replacing the text instead of concatenating it,

Change this line

```
document.getElementById("even").innerHTML = "Even numbers are: " + numbers[i].value;
```

to

```
document.getElementById("even").innerHTML = "Even numbers are : " ;
document.getElementById("even").innerHTML += ", " + numbers[i].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` overwrites your result each time your loop executes. Try this:

```
document.getElementById("even").innerHTML += "Even numbers are: " + numbers[i].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another working example:

```js
function evenNumbers() {
  document.getElementById('even').innerHTML =
    'Even numbers are: ' + [...document.getElementsByClassName("formInput")]
    .filter(x => x.value && x.value !== '0' && x.value % 2 == 0)
    .map(x => x.value)
    .join(', ')
}
```

```css
input {display: block;}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="formInput">
<input type="text" class="formInput">
<input type="text" class="formInput">
<input type="text" class="formInput">
<br>
<button onclick="evenNumbers()">Even Numbers</button>
<br>
<p id="even"></p>
```

Comment: In your code if I left empty values or if I add letters I get result: `p, , 4, , w,`